# What is the origin of Americans sometimes refering to the Second World War "the Good War"?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, warfare

WWII has gone down in American popular memory as "*the* Good War" (later criticized by authors like Studs Terkel, etc.).

But who coined this term? I don't mean the concept, which refers to the idea of "just war," but the particular term.

Was it already used in wartime media and propaganda? Or was it coined later as a contrast to the Cold War, Korean War, or Vietnam?

I've searched academic articles on the subject but they take the term for granted, never addressing its origins.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: Have you checked Google ngram?

Comment: [Just War Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_war_theory) is at least as old as ancient Egypt. Considering that's the first place that had writing, probably as old as humanity. Also, calling a philosophical position a "myth" is a pretty good way to convince users the question is pushing an agenda, rather than seriously asking a question. Might consider making the language in the question much more neutral.

Comment: DOwnvoted because of the claim that it's a myth.   Whether WWII (or any war) might or might not be considered a good war is a matter of one's personal opinions, but it isn't a myth.

Comment: The question seems to be about when the term originated, not whether any particular ware was just, so whether WWII was "good" is tangential, or about the idea of whether war can be just.

Comment: *"WWII has gone down in American popular memory as "the Good War"..."* Not in my experience as an American born in the late 60s who grew up in the U.S. (various parts) and remained there until 2000. I still watch a lot of American TV, read American novels, etc. This is the first time I've heard that usage. (There's "The Great War," but that's primarily British and refers to WWI.) The Wikipedia page for WWII doesn't mention it. So while Studs Terkel may have thought that was common, I really don't think it was or is.

Comment: "popular memory" It must not be that popular, since I have never heard it referred to as such as an American. I agree with TJ.

Comment: I can't speak to the real reason, but it _is_ plausible that WW II is the "good" war as a step down from WW I's "great" war.  Which would make WW III the "just ok" war, I guess?

Comment: @Bobson: Yeah, this does sound like a reference to World War I being called **"_the Great War_"**.  Hard to say if a WWIII would be "_okay_", but if WWIV would be fought with sticks and stones, would that be better or worse?

Comment: never heard it called that

Comment: I've never heard the term.

Comment: I'm a 63-year old American, former naval officer, with a father, father-in-law, and uncles-in-law who all fought in WWII. I've heard it called "WWII", "The Big One", and several unprintable terms, but I have never, ever heard it called "The Good War", either by any of my relatives or at any other time by anyone else. This seems to me to be a newly manufactured term, and one I don't like. There are NO good wars - they're all bad. Sometimes war may be necessary, but necessity does not make them good.

Answer (score 22):

From what I can see, the term "The Good War" when used for WWII was coined *by* Studs Terkel.  If you look at the [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+Good+War&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20Good%20War%3B%2Cc0) as Mark C Wallace suggests, you see two spikes, one small one starting in late sixties, and one large one starting in the late eighties.

In 1965, Marian Maury published [The good war: The UN's world-wide fight against poverty, disease and ignorance](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Good_War.html?id=79hHAAAAIAAJ).  This is not about WWII.

In 1984, Studs Terkel published ["The Good War": An Oral History of World War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good_War).

In this interview, Terkel says "[In the book about World War II, I call the good war. but you notice there quotation marks around the phrase](https://youtu.be/G0AcAF-dbho?t=16)".  This is not concrete, but it does sound like he feels he originated the phrase.  Here's [another interview clip that talks a lot about the feelings about the war](https://youtu.be/UMtbfqpKVBM?t=106).  There's no implication that "The Good War" as a phrase is other than Terkel's "ironic" title.

It seems as if most usages of the term "The Good War" originated from one of those two books, so I think it's safe to say that the term was coined by Terkel himself when used for WWII.  It is hard to prove a negative, but I don't think it was ever used directly before this, or as propaganda.  It looks to me that it has always been used after this with a [hint of irony](https://comb.io/m1spcH).

Comment: Two of your links are commercial, obfuscated by SE and blocked on my network. Could you upgrade them to a free alternative? A screenshot of the ngram-view would also be helpful. (From ngram *alone* this depiction seems not very convincing, as is over-reliance on Google. Not having looked too deep into it, your take seems still correct, from a few angles. Although on the "irony", I'd also point towards [Nietzsche](https://books.google.com/books?id=Rw4u68fxYQMC&lpg=PA387&pg=PA387)… perhaps without a need to upgrade the A.

Comment: Apologies.  Those are the Amazon pages for those two books.  Let me find something less corporate

Comment: (And you are completely correct that this answer is just the result of some google searches)

Comment: And FWIW, I've never read that book by Terkel, and have never heard/seen WWII referred to as "the good war", so it's perhaps not something in common use.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Do note that you aren't allowed to include a screenshot of ngram in a post on SE as the license isn't compatible and the SE license requirements preclude US fair use from applying. Linking or manually recreating the chart are the only correct solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I was just about to include it

Comment: @jamesqf I liked it a lot when I read it as a precocious teenager.  I have no idea if it holds up 35 years later.  Fun fact, Max Brook's [World War Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_Z) was directly inspired it.  It's also good.  (Not the movie, though.  That's terrible.)

Comment: Why did we trust an unreferenced comment? ["Ngram Viewer graphs and data may be freely used for any purpose,"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/info#), and that's done [with gusto across the network](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2469/) Talking about a pic always benefits from having it at hand, you ack the src, it is fair-use, etc. Unless we see a real lawyering argument ref'd, I'd say the comment claiming "incompatible" is just wrong. If it's the only thing stopping you from including the pic, ignore it.